# Unable to compile react application as it says "Module not found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, create-react-app

I have been trying to execute a very simple react application, but for some reason I'm unable to compile it. When i try to compile it in bash using "npm start", i get the error stating "Failed to compile: ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './registerServiceWorker' in '/Users/Pruthvi/Desktop/ReactApplication/my-app/src'"

can anybody help me as I am a new bee to react application!

Comment: You are using `create-react-app`, right? Did you delete or modify any of the files `create-react-app` automatically created when you made the project?

Comment: Yes, I deleted few files which are not required for me to work with. I’m referring a tutorial and I have implemented exactly what was shown. But for some reason, I’m unable to proceed and catch up with the tutorial because of this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) will create a progressive web app, as documented [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app). The progressive web app relies on `registerServiceWorker()` in the `registerServiceWorker.js` file. You have apparently deleted this file, so your project no longer builds.

You have two choices:

1. Keep your project as a progressive web app, in which case you should simply restore the original state you had after first creating.
2. Opt out of the progressive web app features.

In order to opt out of the progressive web app features, you need to modify your `src/index.js` file as follows:

1. Delete the `import` of the `registerServiceWorker`.
2. Delete the `registerServiceWorker()` call.

Your `src/index.js` will then look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
// Deleted -- import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
// Deleted -- registerServiceWorker();
```

Once you've made those modifications to your `index.js`, you can safely delete the `registerServiceWorker.js` file (which it appears you've already done based on the error message you've posted).

The documentation gives a more complete description of [how to opt out](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#opting-out-of-caching) and some of [the consequences of having a progressive web app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#offline-first-considerations).

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked me! i deleted the import registerServiceWorker on top and i was calling it at the end of my code. Forgot to delete or comment that line. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to react and need to build apps fast you can try 
[create-react-app by facebook](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

it a command line tool that will help you build better react app fast with zero configuration you can learn more from the link above and its easy to use

also make sure that you use a good editor that can help you catch errors 
and to help you and give you good answer the second time please provide your code to understand the problem well .

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am just trying to figure out the answer to proceed!