# Modules not found

Tags: reactjs

My project failed to compile saying ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './registerServiceWorker' in 'C:\Users\Jaybee\Desktop\Projects\webzone\src'

[image]

Comment: Try removing registerServiceWorker import from index.js, which i'm assuming you are not using.

Comment: Can you add index.js file and service worker files?

Comment: Look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933951/unable-to-compile-react-application-as-it-says-module-not-found

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'tachyons';

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show index.js file?

And also check out this thread, it may be the same problem:

[Module not found: Can't resolve './registerServiceWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685056/module-not-found-cant-resolve-registerserviceworker)

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'tachyons';
 
ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

Comment: I tried the solution they gave in the link you provided, but it's not working

Comment: Tried more other stuff. and now it's working perfectly

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: i made use of registerServiceWorker() that's why it is not working, so i  did serviceWorker.unregister(); and also imported the import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'; which worked perfectly